# Why sharing webpage on mobile device immediately closes share dialog?

Tags: javascript, php, android, facebook

I'm trying to share webpage using Android device, when I click share it opens Facebook app share dialog for half a second and then immediately disappear. What is the issue on that ? Meta tags are set as defined in share button documentation page.

```
<script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'xxx',
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v2.5'
            });
        };

        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

Meta:

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="http://ex.com/nl_BE/partners" />
        <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
        <meta property="og:title"         content="Ex,  bla bla bla" />
        <meta property="og:description"   content="bla bla bla" />
        <meta property="og:image"         content="http://ex.com/ex/ex/ex/images/how-it-works/step2.jpg" />
```

Comment: do you experience the same issue on desktop? do you observe any errors in the browser's javascript console?

Comment: Its ok with desktop. Some peaople with older android versions say that its ok, but for me and some of my colleagues it not working. Problems Android 6 and 5 is appearing. I dont know how can it be ok on older versions, maybe those people just sharing the content via browser which is ok. But the problem is sharing via Facebook app. And no i didnt see errors in console.